# Non capturing group is not available in the replacement output

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I would like to replace multiple vertical bars (`|`) in the string with a new line (`\n`). However, there are specific conditions, where it shouldn't be replaced, like the color notation string.

Consider the following input:

```
Sample|text||new line|||cFFFFFF00|HEX|colorText in color|this will be inner new line|cFFFFFFFF|HEX|colorReset color. The following goes into the next line too:||hello world
```

Using the following `re.sub` call:

```
re.sub(r"(?:\|\|\w{9}\|HEX\|color.*?|([\|])?\|\w{9}\|HEX\|color)|(\|)", '\n', input)
```

according to [this test](https://regex101.com/r/qx1rpt/1), desired output should be:

```
Sample
text

new line

||cFFFFFF00|HEX|colorText in color
this will be inner new line|cFFFFFFFF|HEX|colorReset color. The following goes into the next line too:

hello world
```

Instead the output is:

```
Sample
text

new line

Text in color
this will be inner new line
Reset color. The following goes into the next line too:

hello world
```

You can test it yourself [here](https://repl.it/repls/NuttyDarkseagreenOrganization).

Apparently, the `re.sub` method is also replacing the non-captured group here, 
which I don't want to happen.

How can I manage to properly replace **only the matched groups** of the pattern with `re.sub`?

Comment: I suspect `re.sub(pattern, lambda x: "\n" if x.group(1) else x.group(), s)`

Comment: In your pattern, you have a redundant group - `([\|])?`, it must be `\|?`, and then the line above should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with a capture group and a `lambda` function in `re.sub`:

```
>>> s=r'Sample|text||new line|||cFFFFFF00|HEX|colorText in color|this will be inner new line|cFFFFFFFF|HEX|colorReset color. The following goes into the next line too:||hello world'
>>> print re.sub(r'(\|\|\w{9}\|HEX\|color.*?|([\|])?\|\w{9}\|HEX\|color)|\|', lambda m: m.group(1) if m.group(1) else '\n', s)
Sample
text

new line
||cFFFFFF00|HEX|colorText in color
this will be inner new line|cFFFFFFFF|HEX|colorReset color. The following goes into the next line too:

hello world
```

- In regex we are using a capture group for the text that we want to keep in replacement string.
- Code in `lambda` function checks for presence of 1st capture group and if it is there then just puts it back otherwise it replaces `|` with `\n`.

Comment: A closure solution is satisfying. Please also add the information about removed non-capturing group since it took me a minute to figure out that lambda isn't the only change here.